# WCF Windows authentication + Console apps on server

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication

I have following setup:

1. WPF client calls WCF SerivceA. Here I have windows authentication with Basic HTTP Binding.
2. The SerivceA will invoke one batch file (.bat or you can say .exe file) from one UNC path. This works. Batch and thus exe called inside it executes.
3. The executed exe now calls to ServiceB. Here, it fails. The error is:
   The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'.

This seems that exectued exe fails to pass the AD user account. It passes following:
IIS APPPOOL\user1 which is not AD user and that is why it fails.

To solve this, I tried impersonation at ServiceA, so I can invoke the batch file under caller's credentials. But no luck. I also tried delegation as well.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a specific user for IIS and registred it for application pool. So now by default, such operations are done under this users's identity and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain from which IPrincipal you did the delegation or impersonation, but you can only use delegation if the server is correclty configured for it, otherwise it will only accept the least priviledge account that performed the request.

Comment: Yes. You are right about server. It is not configured I guess for multiple network hop. So it can be the scenario. But do I require impersonation or not? Can this kind of communication can be done with simple windows authentication?

Comment: depends, if you use delegation, then that means the account that made the request is already registered and authorized in your server, usually in an enterprise that is not the case (your users are usually clean, without roles in your server). If you use impersonation that means you should provide an account with a specific role that your AD knows, usually these are accounts already created for specific purposes in your company